# meaning of ^I in vim and how to not show them?

Tags: vim

Since I have `:set list` in Vim, I often see strange `^I` characters in the beginning of some C-files. Are these the listchars for tabs or what do they mean?
How can I transfer that back to normal? I just want to see end-of-line characters.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

They're tabs. By default, VIM shows all control characers other than EOL as `^n` where `n` is the character of the alphabet corresponding to the character being shown (tab = char #9, `I` = 9th char in alphabet). To stop showing them, use `:set nolist`, but that will turn off EOL display as well.

If you want to see end-of-line chars but not tabs, you can use `listchars` for that. Use `:help listchars` for details, but roughly:

```
:set listchars=tab:\ \ ,eol:$
```

That says, when showing tabs, show a space for the first virtual space it occupies and a space for the subsequent ones; when showing EOLs, use a `$`. (Since tabs can span multiple virtual columns, you get to use two different chars, one for the first column, and one for the others.)

Answer (score 19):

In addition to T.J. Crowder's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505369/11573842), another option would be to make the tabs more pleasing to the eye:

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
```

Comment: You are hereby declared as god, that was what I was looking for for a long time. But it's hard to google for `¬` if you don't know how to write that char.

Comment: This is really easy on the eyes. Excellent suggestion.